# MiniKdc not available from org.springframework.security.kerberos.test.MiniKdc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security-kerberos

I am trying to use "MiniKdc" in my code implementation like "MiniKdc.main(config)" but am getting error "can not resolve symbol 'MiniKdc' ".

I am following this example https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-kerberos-integration

i have added this dependecy in my build.gradle
implementation 'org.springframework.security.kerberos:spring-security-kerberos-test:1.0.1.RELEASE'

i tried to search the dependecy from maven central/repository and i can't find it.

here is the class i am working on, i want to be able to import Minikdc in the second import statement.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.test.MiniKdc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

class KerberosMiniKdc {

    private static final String KRB_WORK_DIR = ".\\spring-security-sso\\spring-security-sso-kerberos\\krb-test-workdir";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String[] config = MiniKdcConfigBuilder.builder()
                .workDir(prepareWorkDir())
                .confDir("minikdc-krb5.conf")
                .keytabName("example.keytab")
                .principals("client/localhost", "HTTP/localhost")
                .build();

        MiniKdc.main(config);
    }

    private static String prepareWorkDir() throws IOException {
        Path dir = Paths.get(KRB_WORK_DIR);
        File directory = dir.normalize().toFile();

        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(directory);
        FileUtils.forceMkdir(directory);
        return dir.toString();
    }
}
```

is there anything am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2021, spring-security-kerberos [is not well maintained](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/issues/157).

I suggest using [Apache Kerby](https://directory.apache.org/kerby/) instead, either directly or via other library like [Kerb4J](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j). See an example [here](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j/blob/master/kerb4j-common/src/test/java/com/kerb4j/KerberosSecurityTestcase.java).

```java
package com.kerb4j;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.kerby.kerberos.kerb.client.KrbConfig;
import org.apache.kerby.kerberos.kerb.server.SimpleKdcServer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;

import java.io.File;

public class KerberosSecurityTestcase {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(KerberosSecurityTestcase.class);
    private static int i = 10000;
    protected int kdcPort;
    private SimpleKdcServer kdc;
    private File workDir;
    private KrbConfig conf;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void debugKerberos() {
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void startMiniKdc() throws Exception {

        kdcPort = i++;

        createTestDir();
        createMiniKdcConf();

        log.info("Starting Simple KDC server on port " + kdcPort);

        kdc = new SimpleKdcServer(workDir, conf);
        kdc.setKdcPort(kdcPort);
        kdc.setAllowUdp(false);
        kdc.init();
        kdc.start();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void stopMiniKdc() throws Exception {
        log.info("Stopping Simple KDC server on port " + kdcPort);
        if (kdc != null) {
            kdc.stop();
            log.info("Stopped Simple KDC server on port " + kdcPort);
        }
    }

    public void createTestDir() {
        workDir = new File(System.getProperty("test.dir", "target"));
    }

    public void createMiniKdcConf() {
        conf = new KrbConfig();
    }

    public SimpleKdcServer getKdc() {
        return kdc;
    }

    public File getWorkDir() {
        return workDir;
    }

    public KrbConfig getConf() {
        return conf;
    }

}
```

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of [Kerb4J](https://github.com/bedrin/kerb4j)*

Comment: "spring-security-kerberos is not well maintained" No longer the case.